# How to set two farpoint data to a single excell file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I know how to set single Farpoint data to print in excel
but I don't know two Farpoint data in one Excell file. I want two Farpoint in a single excel file

```
      string newfilepath = "";
        string newfilepathmnt = "";
        object mngrclassobj = Session["Mngrobj"];
        SessionManager mngrclass = (SessionManager)mngrclassobj;
        newfilepath = mngrclass.ExcelPath + "TruckUtilizationBaseFiguresCompany.xls";
        newfilepathmnt = mngrclass.ExcelPath + "TruckUtilizationbaseFiguresCompany.xls";


        string filepath = newfilepath;
        string filepathmnt = newfilepathmnt; 
        fpsDetails.SaveExcel(filepath, FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.IncludeHeaders.BothCustomOnly);
        fpsMonthlySetup.SaveExcel(filepathmnt, FarPoint.Web.Spread.Model.IncludeHeaders.BothCustomOnly);



        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the sheets to the same Excel workbook, you need to add the sheets to one instance of FpSpread, then save that using SaveExcel.
Please try creating a new FpSpread, adding those sheets to it using FpSpread.Sheets.Add, then call FpSpread.SaveExcel.